# Error: unmatched close parenthesis and I'm sure there's none

Tags: javascript, node.js, logstash-grok

I have a pattern defined and when I match it on a string, it says Error:unmatched close paranthesis but only if I add \ to Support Windows.

The Grok Filter should match a String like this:
logs\01.01.2018\1_00_06\server_console.log

```
let filestamp = pattern.date.parseSync(fileObject.filename);

filestamp.date = filestamp.date.split(".")[2] + "." +n(filestamp.date.split(".")[1]) + "." + filestamp.date.split(".")[0];
filestamp.time = filestamp.time.replace(/_/g, ":");
```

And the Filter in another File

```
exports.date = patterns.createPattern('%{GREEDYDATA}\\%{DATE_EU:date}\\%{DATA:time}\\%{GREEDYDATA}');
```

fileObject.filename is a String like this "logs\01.01.2018\1_00_06\server_console.log"

It only says "Error: unmatched close parenthesis" at the pattern.date.parseSync line, which tells me that there's an missing close parenthesis in the grok pattern, but there's none..

Comment: can you explain what n is or provide code?

Comment: Hi Marvin did you try to escape your backslash in the filename

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to escape your backslashes:

```
let filestamp = pattern.date.parseSync(fileObject.filename.split("\\").join("\\\\"));
```